# New shop feeder size

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I am running 100A to my shop 150 ft from the house. Just making sure my math is right. (2 conductors× 150ft × 21.2 ohms for aluminum × 100 amps)/ 7.24V volt drop= 88,334 cir mils. So looking at 1/0 aluminum

Comment: 2 conductors = Hot & Neutral, right? You're not planning on ever being able to run a 240v load? Or is that Hot & Hot and no 120v loads.

Comment: I plan on running 3 1/0 and 6awg ground. Correct me if im wrong but the way I look at it is your only going to use 2 conductors weather the load is 120 or 240.

Comment: *Most* loads are either pure 120V (e.g., ordinary household stuff, small tools) or pure 240V (e.g., water heaters, big tools). There are some exceptions - e.g., US clothes dryers and ovens typically use 120V for clocks/lights/controls and 240V for heating, so they actually use all 3 wires. But until things get truly huge, hot & neutral wires are the same size and it really doesn't matter much, except to (within reason) balance large 120V loads between the two legs.

Comment: I don't think I explained my self clearly. I know what 120v and 240 volt loads are and that I will be using  both hots and the neutral. For voltage drop calculation no circuit will be more than 300ft. Shop is 150 ft from the house so hot to hot is 300ft and either hot to neutral is 300 ft.

Comment: You calculate voltage drop on actual loads. If your actual loads are 100A, you need to provision 125% of that or 125A.  SInce 1/0 is only 120A, you'll need 2/0.  Are you sure your actual loads are 100A? That's an awful lot.

Comment: 100a at 240v would be 1/0 with aluminum at 150’ you need a sub panel so run the 240 and the voltage drop will be 2.7% , don’t believe me use the south wire voltage drop calculator (that pros and inspectors use in my jurisdiction) sure you could do it with 120 but you may not be able to get a permit as this will imbalance the supply and the NEC code only recommends 3% there is no requirement just 3 % & 5%

Answer (score -1):

Interesting approach you took... most people would just reference an ampacity chart, many are available on the net. Also most people worry too much about voltage drop.  In your shop, it's very unlikely you'd be using the full 100 amps at the same time. Unless you're planning a "grow operation"!

That said, it's safer to go bigger than smaller, it just costs more.  I trust the chart below helps.

[image: ampacity chart]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking through many forums I have found most people say not to worry about VD until around 200ft or better. Just being thorough!